# Create and restore Database using Batch file in Mysql and Windows XP

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am working in WindowsXP . My need is to create  a database and restore that
 database      with data.sql file using batch script . This is needed while user configures the project . I tried the following method but it doesn't work for me.

```
// createdb.bat 
// Password is empty

@echo off 
mysql -u root -p < mysql.sql

//mysql.sql
CREATE DATABASE newdb ;
```

And i have both files in my Desktop . Any help please ?

Comment: Do you get any error or it just does nothing?

Comment: Does the mysql root account have no password?  Try supplying the password via `mysql -u root -pPASSWORD < mysql.sql`.  Or if the script is failing because `newdb` already exists, try adding `drop database newdb;` before the `create database` line.

Comment: how do you invoke createdb.bat?

Comment: I didn't get any error while running the batch file . The command window came and gone but no database is created. There is no database with a name "newdb". I checked with sql yog . Actually i invoke the createdb.bat using Runtime in java . For checking purpose i just double click to run the batch file.

Comment: It might be a path/current directory issue - the file can't be found from where the batch is running. Add `if not exist mysql.sql echo Cant find mysql.sql file!` before the line where it is used. And add a line of just `pause` as the last line, so you get a chance to see what's happened before the window vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for every one to reply my question . As Fuzzy Button said , that was a path issue . I have to set the path to xps.sql file . I have just created the createdb.bat with this code it is working well .

```
@echo off 
set root=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator
cd %root%
mysql -u root  -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS xps";
mysql -u root  xps < xps.sql
```